# How to extract m3u8 from dynamik link?

Tags: php, regex, ajax

This is the main link :

When we enter the above link in the browser it will change to :

But this link is dynamic and some parts of above link will change everytime with refresh. I want to extract the m3u8 link after any refresh. The result of extract to be similar this :

Answer (score 0):

Your original link (the static one) is doing a redirect. In order to follow this redirect you have to specify the right option to your crawler.

So if you're using curl for example you should set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the format is really simple:

If your original link is formatted:

`http://api.hqiptv.net/?{A}/live/0.{B}.m3u8`

the redirect will look like:

`http://s1.hqiptv.net:8080/live/{timestamp}:{A}/{B}.m3u8?{random string}`